# Spring Data JPA, error when I'm trying to select DistinctValue

Tags: java, spring, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I'm getting this error while trying to select distinct value from database using Spring Data JPA.

> Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList] to type
>   [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
>   java.util.List] for value '[a, b,
>   c]'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to
>   type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
>   com.example.million.model.Record]

```
interface RecordRepository: CrudRepository<Record, Long>{

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT million.parentDomain FROM Record million")
    fun findByDomain(domain: String): List<Record>
}

    @Service
class RecordService(val recordRepository: RecordRepository) {

    fun fetchByDomain(domain: String): List<Record> {

        val list = arrayListOf<Record>()

        println(recordRepository.findByDomain(domain))
        recordRepository.findByDomain(domain).forEach { list.add(it) }

        return list
    }
}
```

I have db "million" and table record inside (and one of the field is parent_domain)
**Update:**

```
@Entity
data class Record(
        @Id @GeneratedValue val id: Long? = null,
        var parentDomain: String = "",
        var domain: String = ""
)
```

Comment: Can you share domain/entity class?

Comment: can you provide us with the entities

Comment: sure, updated in post

Comment: You are returning List<Record> but in query you are getting only parentDomain. Please create appropriate constructor to match this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get unique parentDomain you should use following query:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT million.parentDomain FROM Record million where milion.domain = :domain")
fun findByDomain(@Param("domain") domain: String): List<String>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to make a projection and this view can not be mapped to a `Record` try to to make this if you care about the `parentDomain` only

```
interface RecordRepository: CrudRepository<Record, Long>{

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT million.parentDomain FROM Record million")
    fun findByDomain(domain: String): List<String>
}
```

Comment: It will return list of unique parentDomain. My goal is return unique parentDomains for specific domain. For example: domain: a have parentDomain: b x3 times. And I don't want to see it 3 times, I'm trying to find solution where I will have only parentDomain once on my page @KhaledAhmed

Answer (score 0):

Replace "List Record  " with List in interface RecordRepository